# Form submission in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I decided to start a little project in rails 3 and I am a little bit stuck on a form... Where can I specified the f.submit action should go to a special controller / action ?

The code in the form is:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { :action => "login" } do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_field :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

User is defined as @user = User.new in "index" method of "home_controller".

but I have the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"login"}
```

as soon as I run http://0.0.0.0:3000

I am very sorry for this newbee question but I cannot find the routing details (I worked a little bit with rails a couple of years ago but...)

Thanks,
Luc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify any action for f.sumbit.
First of all, you need to make sure you put

```
 resources :users
```

(for example)

in your routes.rb

then if you want to create a user

put

```
  def new

     @user = User.new

 end
```

in your users_controller so you have a page to create new user
or you can put @user=User.new anywhere you like, remember to set
the route correctly

then

```
      def create


    @user = User.new(params[:id])

    if @user.save
        sign_in @user

        redirect_to @user
    else

        render 'new'
    end

 end
```

is the part that does real work after you hit on submit

the actual part that connect your form with everything else is this line

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
```

you can change user to other object, and you can also edit form using update action in a controller.

Hope you got the idea

Comment: In fact, I have a user model with all the REST actions, this is working fine. What I'm trying to do now is to set up a basic login page. I then created a _form.html.erb in app/views/home and I'd like to redirect to the list of users once logged (once login form is submitted)

Comment: You can put @user=Session.new in your page controller under home action, then you should be able to render the partial. Redirection should be handled by create action in session controller

Comment: In fact, in this case I'm not trying to create a new item but I need  to be able to log in the application. As it seems the create method is automatically called, I needed to be able to redirect to another method of the controller. I saw that form_tag could be used to resolve this (first answer of this question), I'll give it a try. thanks a lot for your help. Luc

Comment: I added a specific entry in the routes.rb and it solved the thing. Thanks, Luc

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use REST objects, the mere:

```
form_for @article
```

is enough for the form to find the proper path.

Otherwise, you can use helpers this way:

```
form_tag(:controller => "people", :action => "search", :method => "get", :class => "nifty_form")
```

More info here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html